# How to send the only modified colums in grid?

Tags: extjs

Extjs 4.2

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store:Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields:['id', 'subject', 'content'],
        idProperty:'id',
        autoSync:true,
        proxy:{
            api:{update:'update'}
        }
    }),
    columns:[
        {text:'subject', dataIndex:'subject'},
        {text:'content', dataIndex:'content'}
    ]
});
```

when the column 'subject' changed ,store proxy will send the data with 'content ',but i just need 'subject'.

Comment: did you use `cellediting` plugin?

Comment: rowEditor or Ext.form.Panel

Answer (score 0):

maybe [store.sync()](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync) would do the trick. In Extjs 3.4 there is a function [store.save](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-save) i can`t find equivalent method in 4.2 version